# ESP32-S2 TFT Feather - analog to digital in Arduino

Tags: arduino, esp32, adc

I have a gas sensor that I am trying to read. I have connected the sensor to the analog input of ESP-S2 TFT Feather. When I change the analog to digital and read the measured voltage, the measured voltage is very very high. I figured out the resolution of this board is 13 bit. But, the measured voltage is still very high.

```
 int analogInPin = A2; 
 void readco() {
 // read the analog in value:
 sensorValue = 0;
 const int res = 8191; //resolution = 13-bit and 2^13 - 1 = 8191
 
  sensorValue = analogRead(analogInPin) + sensorValue;   
  iaq_data.co_0=(float) sensorValue*3.3/res;
```

Comment: If you are using Arduino-ESP32, the default ADC resolution is 12-bit except for ESP32S3. Read the [doc](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/arduino-esp32/en/latest/api/adc.html) to see how to set the `analogReadResolution()`.

Answer (score 0):

From the ESP32-S2 docs found [here](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/stable/esp32s2/api-reference/peripherals/adc.html),

> Resolution of ESP32-S2 ADC raw results under Single Read mode is 12-bit

Are you sure your resolution is 13 bit?

Also, you seem to be adding `sensorValue` to itself every time. You initialise it to 0 every time so it should not matter but I would remove that.

This code should work:

```
int 12_bit_resolution = 4095; // 2^12 4096 - 1
input_voltage = analogRead(analogInPin) * (3.3 / 12_bit_resolution);
```